# Not able to access hyperlink column inside gridview from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I want to access the `HyperLinkField` column of the GridView from code behind but I am unable to do so.

I have the column in my dataset but I am still not able to use it.

My `HyperLinkField` column is named `Status`.

[image: img]

Here is what I tried:

```
UltraWebGrid1.DataSource = ObjPriDsGrid;
UltraWebGrid1.DataBind();

string StrPriStatus = "";

for (int IntPriI = 0; IntPriI < UltraWebGrid1.Rows.Count; IntPriI++)
{
    if (UltraWebGrid1.Rows[IntPriI].Cells[6].Text.Trim() != null)
    {
        StrPriStatus = UltraWebGrid1.Rows[IntPriI].Cells[6].Text.Trim();
    }
    else
    {

    }
    if (StrPriStatus == "5")
    {
        UltraWebGrid1.Rows[IntPriI].Cells[8].Text = ""; // Not getting status column here
    }
}
```

Here is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="UltraWebGrid1" ShowHeader="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    DataKeyNames="mkey" OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound" Width="98%" Height="30%"
    PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="Grid1_PageIndexChanging"
    ShowFooter="true" CssClass="Grid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../../../Images/plus.png" />
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlGrid" runat="server" Style="display: none">
                    <asp:GridView ID="Grid2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="600px"
                        CssClass="ChildGrid">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="80px" DataField="RefMkey" HeaderText="Mkey" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CurrentUser" HeaderText="Current User" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="180px" DataField="Department" HeaderText="Current Department" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100px" DataField="remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="0px" DataField="mkey" Visible="false" HeaderText="Mkey" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="8%" DataField="Doc_No" HeaderText="IW/ No" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%" DataField="Doc_Date" HeaderText="IW/ Date" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="12%" DataField="DocType" HeaderText="Doc type" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="15%" DataField="Party_Name" HeaderText="Party Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="0" Visible="true" DataField="Status_Flag" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%" DataField="LastAction_datetime" HeaderText="Last Action Date" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%" DataField="CurrStatus" HeaderText="Current Status" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="10%" DataField="Type_desc" HeaderText="Resp Dept" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="12%" DataField="UserName" HeaderText="Resp User" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="8%" DataField="No_Of_Days" HeaderText="No of days" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField ItemStyle-Width="5%" DataNavigateUrlFields="Mkey, Status, Doc_No"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Administration/Dispatch/Inward/FrmInwardNextAction.aspx?Inward_mkey={0}&Status={0}&IWNO={0}"
            HeaderText="Status" DataTextField="Status" Target="_blank" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField ItemStyle-Width="5%" DataNavigateUrlFields="Mkey, Status, Doc_No"
            HeaderText="View" DataTextField="View" Target="_blank" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/Administration/Dispatch/Inward/InwardDocDetails.aspx?Key={0}&Status={0}&IWNO={0}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Column 8 is a `BoundField` named "Current Status", but column 12 is a `HyperLinkField` named "Status". Which status column are you actually trying to get? Right now, you are going for column 8, which is not a hyperlink.

Comment: @j.f.: I am talking about column `12` I just added to check as 8 in code behind. When I debugged for `UltraWebGrid1.Rows[IntPriI].Cells[12].Text` for `12` I got it as blank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns like HyperLinkField and CheckBoxField behave a little differently than BoundField. They don't just simply contain text like BoundField. You have to get the control within the cell. You can get the child controls of the cell using the `Controls` collection. We know that specifically for a `HyperLinkField`, the HyperLink will be the first control in the collection.

```
HyperLink hyp = (HyperLink)UltraWebGrid1.Rows[IntPriI].Cells[12].Controls[0];
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it like this

```
if (StrPriStatus == "5")
{
   HyperLink HyperLinkObj = (HyperLink)UltraWebGrid1.Rows[IntPriI].Cells[12].Controls[0];
   HyperLinkObj.Text = "";
}
```